# Can anyone recommend a slick, professional looking image carousel?

Tags: asp.net, image

I am working on a .NET web app. I need to display images from the file system. Can anyone recommend a slick, professional looking image carousel (even if there is a cost) that has allows the user to rotate through the images at the bottom and then displays the larger image when the thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: Just to be clear: you're looking for an "image carousel" control, right, not a piece of hardware.

Comment: yes, an image carousel control. preferably not flash.

Answer (score 0):

[This one's pretty nice](http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/3d_carousel_menu_xml_3.0.html), and it's only 12 bucks. Lots of configurability. It's in Flash; I don't know if that's an issue for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery plugin Cycle is really nice, it allows a lot of customization.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

This one is really nice if you're looking for a Javascript solution...

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

It has more of the CoverFlow style to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole collection of them to choose from :)

http://www.net-kit.com/best-animated-jquery-slideshows/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking, I can heartily recommend [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/).